# selenium webdriver not working propely in firefox

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I just did

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://google.co.in")
```

Which version of selenium should I have to install 
1) If I have to use Firefox 32.0 only.

Error is

> WebDriverException: Missing 'marionetteProtocol' field in handshake

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type in cmd `pip install selenium` it will directly install the latest selenium and hope it will work if not please send the error which you are getting.

Comment: You are using too old browser. Please check the link(https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases"). You can code with Python also check the link (https://github.com/jasham/naukri/blob/master/n_update.py)

Comment: ya thats why I mentioned Firefox 32.0 only, not upgraded version.I have to use 32.0 only

Comment: with firefox 32.0 by any chance using selenium is possible ?

Comment: Selenium Webdriver 2.43.1 will work fine please check (https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7935)

Answer (score 1):

Download **Selenium Webdriver 2.43.1 jars** for Firefox 32.0

Comment: is it for python too?

Comment: as per my knowledge yes

Comment: Where can I get the link to download?